# gets.chomp for coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, coffeescript

In ruby, using `gets.chomp`, I can ask the user for input and save it as a variable that I can use. For example...

```
puts "In which city do you stay?"   
city = gets.chomp  
puts "The city is " + city
```

Is there something in coffeescript (or javascript) that can do the same? I have looked into javascript's--`readline`, `prompt`, `process.stdin`...

These work somewhat, but I can't find a way how I can save that user input as a variable that I can use and process for later.

Comment: Are you using something like Node.js for your command line app?

Comment: I used node.js to test readline, prompt and process.stdin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you are writing an application to run on the console (not in a browser), here's a couple of pointers for your:

First one explains how it is done, using low level mechanisms:

http://st-on-it.blogspot.no/2011/05/how-to-read-user-input-with-nodejs.html

Second one makes it bearable:

http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/9103188408/commander-js-nodejs-command-line-interfaces-made-easy